# Sqlcipher Failed allocating 1638057 bytes for text/blob at 0,0

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

So, I have a Cordova app which uses sqlcipher to talk to the database. There is a particular `insert` statement where I have to insert a lot of data into the Db.
So the insert fails giving me the following error :

```
Failed to allocate 1638057 bytes for text/blob at 0,0
```

After researching about it, I found out that sqlcipher has a limit of 1 MB. One solution I found out was upgrading to version 3.5.7 where sqlcipher has a dynamic size.

After I upgraded to 3.5.7 I when starting the app, the app stops working and the logs show me the following error at

> SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.something.offline-upC4lfhZqsaVGORPq1Gtgg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.something.offline-upC4lfhZqsaVGORPq1Gtgg==/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/org.something.offline-upC4lfhZqsaVGORPq1Gtgg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlcipher.so"

I searched about the error online but couldn't get any solution.

EDIT : Solved the above problem. It was a packaging issue.I forgot to import the liquibase.so files
Now I'm getting a new error : https://pastebin.com/jzX9AqEX

Comment: This sounds like an application packaging problem, since libsqlcipher.so can't be found. You might inspect the package to ensure that the native libraries are present.

Comment: @StephenLombardo Thanks for the input. Actually it was a packaging issue. But now I am getting a different issue. Can you check this : https://pastebin.com/jzX9AqEX

Comment: @krishansace - Sorry, I'm not sure what that issue could be, but it doesn't look like it is related to SQLCipher

Comment: @StephenLombardo Oh.. no  problem. I actually got the error after changing the sqlcipher version. If I revert it back , this new error is gone